# Are bool arrays treated differently in terms of decaying?

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion, int, boolean

Consider an example where I want to create an array of arrays of `bool`:

```
int main() {
    using type = bool[1];

    bool a1[1] = {true};
    bool a2[1] = {true};
    bool a3[1] = {true};

    type block_types[3] = {{a1}, {a2}, {a3}};
}
```

This code compiles for **Clang 7.0.0**, **GCC 8.2** and **MSVS v19.16**.

Now, let's change `bool` to `int`:

```
int main() {
    using type = int[1];

    int a1[1] = {1};
    int a2[1] = {1};
    int a3[1] = {1};

    type block_types[3] = {{a1}, {a2}, {a3}};
}
```

Now, the code stops compiling on any of those compilers, with errors similar to:

> ```
> error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
> type block_types[3] = { {a1}, {a2}, {a3}};
>                                         ^
> ```

<sub>Note: this exact error message comes from GCC 8.1.</sub>

Why is that? Why are `bool[]`s treated differently than `int[]`s? What's the rationale behind this?

Comment: You are assigning out of bounds for `a1`, `a2` and `a3`. You probably meant to assign to `a1[0]` etc. Does this change anything?

Comment: `a1[1]` is not an assignment. There are no out of bounds assignments here.

Comment: `a1[0] = {true}` (and friends) looks wrong. Don't you need at least 1 element?

Comment: @Fureeish after your editing, now it becomes wrong. Look at  Sam's comment

Comment: Yeah, well... It seems like I am **too** tired. Please ignore my (*double*) mistake.

Comment: I've got warnings turned on.  The first bool case, `{{a1}, {a2}, {a3}}` are all treated as address converted to bool, and since they are all valid addresses (i.e., not nullptr), they all get converted to true.

Comment: Yup. The key difference is, you can't convert `int*` to `int`, but you *can* convert `bool*` (or any pointer at all) to `bool`.

Comment: @Eljay that should be the answer. Really does make sense - I completely missed the implicit convestion from pointer to `bool`.

Comment: Just found a helpful article about this: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2011-09/msg00305.html

Comment: cant answer right now but i think what is going on is the bools decay to a pointer which can then decay into a bool.  the int case doesn't work because there isn't an implicit conversion from a pointer to an integer, only a bool

Answer (score 1):

In the first, block_types is an array of three arrays of one boolean.  Each of the inner blocks in your initializer needs to provide a boolean value.  You've given a pointer for each one, and pointers will convert to bool.

In the second, block_types is an array of three arrays of one integer, and each inner block of your initializer needs to provide an integer value.  You have again given pointers, and they don't convert to integer.

So, no: the arrays are decaying on the same rules, but resulting pointer conversions distinguish the examples.